# Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk'?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios-simulator, xcode8

I have just installed the xcode 8.0 and upgrade my project to swift 3. I was using swift 2.2 and xcode 7.3.1.

But getting following error:

> Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk'
>
> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please provide the full build log.  How are you referencing the 9.3 SDK?  Xcode 8 comes with the 10.0 SDK.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This happened to me when I had simultaneously installed both Xcode 7 and 7.3 and after automatic update I was left with 8.0 only.

One indication that something got messed up was output of `xcodebuild -sdk -version` in terminal:

```
DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '<DVTFilePath:0x7fd810db4c50:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS3.0.sdk'>': SDK with name 'watchos3.0' being superceded by SDK with 'watchos3.0'.
```

**Solution:**

1. Quit Xcode
2. go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/`
3. remove the `iPhoneOS9.3.sdk` folder from that directory.  Be sure to make an external copy if you still need it so you can put it back later.
4. restart Xcode, clean, and build
5. ???
6. PROFIT

**UPDATE:**

According to @tsafrir comment, delete also 'iPhoneOS9.3.sdk' for simulator folder:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhon‌​eSimulator.platform/‌​Developer/SDKs`

Comment: In addition to deleting the soft link for `iPhoneOS9.3.sdk`, there is also one for the simulator which is located at`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

Comment: Now I have an error `There is no SDK with the name or path '<my-path>/iphoneos` and there's no iOS SDK anymore.

Answer (score 9):

The `iPhoneOS9.3.sdk` for the simulator is at `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`.

1. quit xcode
2. delete
3. clean
4. build again.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but selecting - "Use Legacy Compiler Version": Yes, removed that warning for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

Answer (score 0):

It happen due to old xcode still in system and you updated new one. 
For fixing this use following step.

1. Quit Xcode
2. go to
   Simulator and iPhoneOS. platform

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
 3. remove the iPhoneOS9.x.sdk folder from that directory. Be sure to
    make an external copy if you still need it so you can put it back
    later.

4. Copy old xcode  sdk (iPhoneOS9.x(Updated SDK))
   Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/ iPhoneOS9.3(Updated SDK)

5> Paste this SDK in new  XCODE 8 in this folder 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/

6> Clean and Build.

Fixed