# Swift with iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk in iPhoneSimulator directory doesn't compile

Tags: swift, sdk, simulator

Upgraded to Swift 3.0 with Xcode 8.3.3 but got this error with first simple app build:

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1 error: Swift does not support the SDK
>   'iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk'

So I followed the steps here: [Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635735/swift-does-not-support-the-sdk-iphonesimulator9-3-sdk)

including renaming and removing the file, then cleaning and building the project.

But then I started getting a different error, saying: Can not load underlying CoreGraphics. (see attachments).first image. [image: second error]

So first the compiler complained about the presence of the 9.3 simulator and then it complained that it couldn't be found.

I also tried renaming the 9.3 Simulator but still does not resolve problem.

What can I do to get my environment to be correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok the important part was that I had to actually delete the file, which probably freed up a file handle for it.

I had tried to rename it and leave it in the same directory, and move it to another directory.

But when I actually moved it to the Trash, then I was able to clean, build and run the project.

Comment: I also found that I had to remove the 9.3 SDK from the iPhoneOS.platform directory (yes I made a copy first) when I ran the app on my actual iPhone. So if you are running on your phone and get this error drill down in that directory to find the SDK folder and remove the 9.3 SDK file from that subdirectory as well.